# Building FLTK without root access

Tags: bash, build, permissions

I'm trying to build FLTK without root access. The configuration allows to change the output `bin`, `lib` and `include` directories to where I want, so I put them in my home directory. I add the paths to the `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables in my `.bashrc` file and I don't get any permission problems when running `make install`.

But I need to install the desktop files as well. And when I run `make install-desktop`, I get a permission error in `/usr/share/applications`:

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file `/usr/share/applications/fluid.desktop': Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-linux] Error 1
make: *** [install-desktop] Error 2
```

What can I do about this? Is there something else I can add to my `.bashrc` file to make this possible, or do is using root/`sudo` the only way?

Comment: Do you need to install this application on all users desktop or just for you ?

Comment: @Aserre Just for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to modify the installation script to do what you want.

1. Edit the `makefile` file and see which scripts are called for the `install-desktop` rule
2. Edit the listed files, and replace every occurence of `/usr/share/applications/fluid.desktop` by `~/.local/share/applications/fluid.desktop`
3. Run the makefile again

You should have every permission to write on your `~/.local/share/applications/`, which is used for a specific user. `/usr/share/applications/` is used for every users on the computer and requires elevated permissions.